# Retrieve Json Objects in WebApi sent by C# Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple windows phone app and a web api that doesn't store anything in a database. The app sends two values name & email in JSON format as shown below.

```
 var sendjsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sendemailandnumber);
 var senddata = new StringContent(sendjsonstring, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 await client.PostAsync(serviceurl, senddata);
```

The service url is localhost:1401/api/userdetails

Route Details are,

```
  name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
```

I have a HTTP post controller in my Web Api as below,

```
[HttpPost]
public List<UserDetails> GetUserDetails([FromBody] UserDetails details)
{
     string name, email;
}
```

How do I retrieve the JSON values in the controller and assign them to the variables, my solution's aren't working?

Comment: You haven't put `[HttpPost]` on the `GetUserDetails` method

Comment: Next you need to show us what the `controller` `RoutePrefix` or `RouteTable` is and the `serviceurl`

Comment: It would be helpful if you said specifically what solutions you've tried and how they're not working. Do they error out? Or is the `details` variable null?

Comment: There is, I ommited it.

Comment: put a breakpoint inside GetUserDetails method and let us know if it fires?

Comment: The details variable is null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have available the values:

```
public List<UserDetails> GetUserDetails([FromBody] UserDetails details)
{
    //use this
    string name = details.Name;
}
```

This is true IF what you are posting can be converted into a UserDetails object.

Comment: Does the controller name in the serviceurl have to match the controller name in the webapi,does it need to be exact??

Comment: @DrManhattan You should be posting to, for example: http://localhost:12345/api/CONTROLLERNAME/GetUserDetails

Comment: That was the solution and above one as well,, thanks man.. Will mark this as answer asap..